# Cocoa: Stopping the field editor from auto-completing on space key

Tags: cocoa, autocomplete, subclass, nstextview, fieldeditor

I have a custom view with several `NSTextField` controls for which I want to supply custom auto-completions and  I have successfully implemented all that using the `NSTextFieldDelegate` Protocol.  The auto-completions are full names or place names, depending on which text field is being edited.

The issue is that the auto-completions almost always contain a space character and so if the user is typing something that matches a suggestion, but doesn't want to accept that suggestion, the field editor will accept the suggestion when user presses the space key.  I want the field editor to accept the suggestion using the tab key only.

I understand that this will involve subclassing `NSTextView` to provide a custom field editor, and this is [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/Subclassing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000937-CJBJHGAG) as being the acceptable way, however it's not clear to me what methods I need to override and what the overridden methods need to do, in order to get me what I want.

Can anyone suggest how this is achieved?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of autocompletion words you're describing?

Comment: @RobKeniger I have edited my question.  Where ya been man?  I can't get things done if you don't hold my hand every step of the way!  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I admit that I'd been fumbling with this question for quite some time earlier, before [I discovered an acceptable answer via Google-fu.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163646/how-to-make-nssearchfield-send-action-upon-autocompletion/5360535#5360535) The magic code, blatantly stolen from the original answerer:

```
@interface MLFieldEditor : NSTextView @end

@implementation MLFieldEditor


-  (void)insertCompletion:(NSString *)word forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange movement:(NSInteger)movement isFinal:(BOOL)flag {
    // suppress completion if user types a space
    if (movement == NSRightTextMovement) return;

    // show full replacements
    if (charRange.location != 0) {
        charRange.length += charRange.location;
        charRange.location = 0;
    }

    [super insertCompletion:word forPartialWordRange:charRange movement:movement isFinal:flag];

    if (movement == NSReturnTextMovement)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MLSearchFieldAutocompleted object:self userInfo:nil];
    } }

@end
```

([Additional reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981439/how-to-prevent-nssearchfield-from-overwriting-entered-strings-using-the-first-au))

Comment: Great stuff - I'll give it a try and let you know.  Give Morticia a kiss from me.

Comment: @trojanfoe Glad to help! Don't forget to grant the bounty. :)

Comment: Sorry - I thought that was automatic :)