# Swift & NSTextField: How to work with Text Completion

Tags: swift, delegates, nstextfield

I want to create autocomplete list like this for `NSTextField`:
[image]

I have found this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/1428925-control

```
optional func control(_ control: NSControl, 
             textView: NSTextView, 
          completions words: [String], 
  forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, 
  indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String]
```

Can somebody please explain how to use this on any example? 
I can't really understand.

I tried to implement this, but nothing works. You can find my code below.

Thank you in advance

### My code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var InputField: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    InputField.delegate = self
}

func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextField, completions words: [String], forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String] {

    let words = ["Hello", "Brother"]

    return words
}

@IBAction func CompleteButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    print("pressed")
    InputField.complete(nil)
```

}
    }

But if I try to press the button, I get this error in my console:

```
pressed
[NSTextField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10066ae00
[General] -[NSTextField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10066ae00
```

Comment: Do you understand delegates?

Comment: @Willeke I'm a beginner in this :) Just added my code, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextField` doesn't implement `complete:`, `NSTextView` does. `NSTextField` uses a `NSTextView`, the field editor, to edit its contents, see [Text Fields, Text Views, and the Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA). Use `currentEditor()` to get the field editor from the text field.

```
@IBAction func completeButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    inputField.currentEditor()?.complete(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method allows you to control the suggestions only. (example: order, filter etc..)

So, if you don't want to customize your suggestions, you would just have to return words:

```
optional func control(_ control: NSControl, 
             textView: NSTextView, 
          completions words: [String], 
  forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, 
  indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String] {
  return words
}
```

Comment: thank you!

I just tried to implement this and it doesn't work :(

Added my code to issue.

Comment: You need to list NSControlTextEditingDelegate in your the header of your class. You can then implement textDidChange to get a notification everytime the text changes. Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558182/preventing-spacebar-from-selecting-first-suggestion-in-autocomplete-text-field