# NSTextField: error on calling completions by .complete(nil) in swift 5

Tags: swift, autocomplete, delegates, nstextfield, nstextview

I'm using `NSTextField` with complections and they work fine by pressing `F5` key.

But I have to call complections programmatically and I'm using `complete(:)` for this, but I get an error and crash every time I 
I tried to call `InputField.complete(nil)`.

You can find my code below.

Thank you in advance

### My code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate, NSControlTextEditingDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var InputField: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    InputField.delegate = self
}

func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextField, completions words: [String], forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String] {

    let words = ["Hello", "Brother"]

    return words
}

@IBAction func CompleteButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    print("pressed")
    InputField.complete(nil)
}
}
```

But if I try to press the button, I get this in my console:

```
pressed
[NSTextField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10066ae00
[General] -[NSTextField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10066ae00
```

Comment: Why using NSTextField, Use UITextField

Comment: @KeshuRai because it's MacOS, not iOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift & NSTextField: How to work with Text Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013581/swift-nstextfield-how-to-work-with-text-completion)

Comment: @Willeke ,yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@IBAction func completeButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    inputField.currentEditor()?.complete(nil)
}
```